# Differential calculus on Coq

Tags: coq

I want to reperesent the exact value of differential calculus on Coq, not approximation.

I defined the inductive type represents the differentiation of the real number as you can see below.

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

Inductive myR:=
| mR : R -> myR 
| Diff : myR -> myR.
```

This is not interesting.
Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Coquelicot`, [`Derive` is defined](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Derive.html#Derive) as

```
Definition Derive (f : R → R) (x : R) := real (Lim (fun h ⇒ (f (x+h) - f x)/h) 0).
```

Answer (score 2):

In the standard library, there is the module [Reals.Rderiv](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Rderiv.html), which defines the derivative relation `D_in` to be that a function `f : R -> R` has derivative `d : R -> R` at `x0` if the limit of `(f(x) - f(x0)) / (x - x0)` as `x` goes to `x0` is `d x0` (and everything restricted to a domain `D` subset of `R`).

This is pretty much the standard definition I learned in my first calculus course, and in particular taking the limit ensures that you get the exact derivative.